# Trying to prove an statement from Complex Analysis Stein book

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Now, but apparently, my solution is not correct as I am applying comparison test wrongly. How may I fix this?

Comment: What does the inequality $a_n |z|^n \geq -(|z|(L+\epsilon))^n$ mean if $a_n$ is not real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is invalid. What you are saying is something like this: If $a_n \geq 0$ then $\sum a_n $ is divergent because $a_n \geq -1$ and $\sum -1$ is divergent.  The comparison test you are trying to use is applicable only when both series have positive terms.

For  a correct argument show that $a_nz^{n}$ does not tend to $0$ if $|z| >R$. (In fact $|a_nz^{n}| >1$ for $n$ sufficiently large). This would imply divergence.